# dmesg: `PME: Spurious native interrupt!`

Tags: linux, debian, pci-express, interrupts, dmesg

I am running `Linux debian 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux` (and dual-booting Windows 11, fast boot is turned off) and I see this line in my `dmesg` output:

```
[ 7478.982052] pcieport 0000:00:08.1: PME: Spurious native interrupt!
```

This is not printed very often and does not cause any functionality errors (at least I do not know about them), but I would like to know what this log line means and whether I should be worried.

`lshw` output: https://pastebin.com/Fyn6At9U

`lspci` output: https://pastebin.com/eBzaw6iC